# How to tell Tomcat which connector to use for websocket (JSR356)

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am using Tomcat 7.0.59 and currently testing websocket on it. It works fine by itself, but in my production environment, i need to take into account the fact there is an Apache server as the front end, and Tomcat is serving as the application server through the mod_jk connector.

Since it seems websocket does NOT work with mod_jk, and i can not change any part on the Apache side, the only solution left for me is to use a different port (or connector).

**First solution**: Add Tyrus server standalone jars in Tomcat (ugly for me -- not tested, should work, although i am wondering about potential conflict with Tomcat).

**Second solution**: Tell Tomcat websocket to 'bind' on another port (connector).

How can i setup the second solution?
Which paramaters can be passed to Tomcat's websocket by web.ml or server.xml ?

I have been searching the web and Tomcat doc for this subsject, but haven't found topics around these questions.